# Selenium looping sendKeys

Tags: java, facebook, loops, selenium, for-loop

So I have gotten far enough to locate the textbox on facebook, and send a person a message. Now I want to see if I can create a loop to send multiple messages at once. My current problem is I have a for loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    messageBox.sendKeys("My friend's name " + i + " ");
    messageBox.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
}
```

However, I can only do this once. So It will print "My friend's name0" and then stop. Java says: element is not attached to the page document.

I am assuming that because i sent the message, some part of the Inspect Element has changed? Is there a way to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

Get Friend's name from Excel sheet

Make a Method for get data from excel file:-

```
public static void fn_FetchExcelData(String FilePath,String ColumnName) throws IOException{
               String WbookPath=FilePath;
                  Workbook WBookObj=fn_GetWorkbook(FilePath);
                  Sheet SheetObj=WBookObj.getSheetAt(0);
                  Row FstRowObj=SheetObj.getRow(0);
                  int cellCount=FstRowObj.getLastCellNum();
                  int columnNumber=0;
                  ArrayList<String> AL=new ArrayList<String>();
                  for(int j=0; j<cellCount;j++){
                      if(FstRowObj.getCell(j, Row.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK).getStringCellValue().trim().equalsIgnoreCase(ColumnName)){
                          columnNumber=j;
                          break;
                      }
                  }
                  int rowcnt=SheetObj.getLastRowNum();
                     for(int i=1;i<=rowcnt;i++){
                      Cell fstcellObj=SheetObj.getRow(i).getCell(columnNumber, Row.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK);
                      String ColumnVal=fstcellObj.getStringCellValue();


               AL.add(ColumnVal);

call excel method & use it



  fn_FetchExcelData("Your excel data path");
                  int j;
                     int size = AL.size();
                        for(j=0;j<size;j++)
                        {
                            System.out.println(AL.get(j));

                 messageBox.sendKeys(AL.get(j));
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind i figured it out, I just added

```
                  WebElement messageBox = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//textarea[@class='uiTextareaAutogrow _552m']"));
                wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(messageBox));
```

Again to the loop and it works. However it is VERY slow.